# How to change function of bigPlayButton in video js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, video.js

I'm showing the **bigPlayButton** when my video is playing. I want video stop when **bigPlayButton** is clicked and video play when **bigPlayButton** is clicked again.

At first, I used `$( ".video-js" ).hasClass('vjs-playing')` to detect video is playing but it don't work well in mobile.

```
 var myPlayer = videojs("vod");
 myPlayer.bigPlayButton.on('click', function(){
   if($( ".video-js" ).hasClass('vjs-playing')) { 
     myPlayer.pause(); 
   } 
});
```

Is there any way to change function of **bigPlayButton** to **PlayToggle**?

Comment: Can you share your code or css which you have tried so far?

Comment: var myPlayer = videojs("vod");
myPlayer.bigPlayButton.on('click', function()
    {
        if($( ".video-js" ).hasClass('vjs-playing'))
        {
            myPlayer.pause();
        }
    });

Comment: Check this link https://gist.github.com/rchrd2/4cafdae8d8add51f2a9d

Comment: Yes. I tried that but it add new function to button. When I click bigPlayButton, existing play() function work and mess new function.